# Hurtling through/across

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, prepositions

1. Our planet is hurtling **through** space.
2. Our planet is hurtling **across** the universe.
3. Our planet is hurtling **through** the universe.

Do all three of these sentences convey the same meaning? Are all of them grammatically correct?

Comment: hurtling implies a chaotic/dangerous/uncontrolled movement, but our planet seems to take a very predictable and steady path...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Across the universe" suggest "from one side to the other".  And "through the universe" similarly suggests that it is travelling a large proportion of the size of the universe; at least it suggest "between galaxies".  You might use these figuratively or dramatically in a science fiction (or space opera) context.  But the Earth isn't going far from the sun ever.

"Through space" is probably better.

Comment: Well no, but then the sun itself, and indeed the galaxy itself, are also hurtling through the universe. So both"hurtling through space" and "hurtling through the universe" are truisms.

Comment: I still feel that the "universe" versions suggest travel between galaxies.

Comment: Well, as I say, the galaxy itself *is* hurtling through the universe (for whatever definition of "hurtling"). Hence we are hurtling with it.